# WebApi 2 call using HttpWebrequest/HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5

I need to make a webApi call to the controller from a C# code .Net 4.5

My Api controller looks like:

```
[Route("api/GetData/{id}/{createDate}")]
public List<DataModel> GetData(int id, DateTime createDate)
{
    var dataDb = new DataDb(SqlConnectionString);
    var result = dataDb .GetSalesData(id, createDate);
    return result;
}
```

How do i call the above controller using c#, 
I dont want to pass parameter in url for e.g. "http://wks337:8989/api/GetData/1/2013-06-11/12337" instead add it to header/body (any best approach) rather than Uri.

I tried using HttpWebRequest as:

```
string serviceUrl = url + methodName + "//";
dynamic parameterObj = new ExpandoObject();
parameterObj.id= definitionId;
parameterObj.createDate= jobDate;

string strParameter = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameterObj);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(parameters);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But it always gets me 404 error.
I know am doing something or entirely wrong, Could anyone guide me to the correct code.

I tried google but example suggested to pass parameter in Url which I dont want.

Comment: why are you trying using `POST`? while your `GetData` accepts only `GET` ?

Comment: If you want `POST`, add the `HttpPost` attribute to your action.

Comment: Coz When I try using GET then I get error as "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type".

Comment: @Yuval i stil get same 404 error after adding [HttpPost] attribute to action.

Comment: Is there any different approach through which its possible any code example would do.

Comment: What does your actual URL look like?

Comment: "http://localhost:8989/api/GetData/"

Comment: @JoshuaI Change your name GetData to something else..routs are smart and automatic reads the "Get" as a Get-method.

Answer (score 4):

the problem here is that your controller method is a `Get[HttpGet]` method and in your calling code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Method = "POST";
```

your are making a `"POST"` request. if you want the parameters to go  in the request body rather than url. you would need to make your action method `[HttpPost]`. First create a model class that will bundle up your parameters as

```
public class GetDataParameters
{
  Public int Id {get; set;}, 
  public DateTime createDate {get; set;}
}
```

then in the controller

```
[Route("api/GetData/")]
[HttpPost]
public List<DataModel> GetData([FromBody] getDataParameters)
{
    var dataDb = new DataDb(SqlConnectionString);
    var result = dataDb .GetSalesData(getDataParameters.id, getDataParameters.createDate);
    return result;
}
```

now you should be able to make a post request by passing parameters in the body. Also as a suggestion instead of writing all that code your self for making requests have a look at [HastyApi](https://github.com/lukesampson/HastyAPI) or even better [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)

Comment: Adding [HttpPost] doesn't make a difference, i get the same error. If i pass the same thing in url it works e.g.:   http://localhost:8989/api/GetClipGridData/2013-06-11/12337

Comment: The URL in your above example is contains GetClipGridData not GetData?

Comment: @strickt01 the url will be ".../api/GetData. What are you using to test this. Try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and add request body to your post request as '{id ="12337", createDate="2013-06-11"}'

Comment: @PreetSingh I know the URL should be api/GetData as per the Web API route but in all @Joshua I's example URLs for successful calls he specifies `http://localhost:8989/api/GetClipGridData...` - which leads me to think that his 404 may be something to do with this confusion...

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake above in listing the Url cause of copy paste, its    localhost:8989/api/GetData/1/2013-06-11

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

using `HttpClient`

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
   //My Custom Class
   var request = new CreateAppRequest()
   {
      userAgent = "myAgent",
    
   };

   var response = await client.PostAsync("https://domain.com/CreateApp", 
    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), 
        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")); 
 }
```

> A Nuget package available, using `httpclient` and `Newtonsoft`
>
> **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client**

```
// HTTP POST
var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Get the URI of the created resource.
    Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;
}
```

[msdn reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 0):

The route for your action specifies that the parameters are passed as part of the URL. If you wanted to ensure that the parameters are passed in the body then you'd need to decorate your method as such:

```
[Route("api/GetData")]
[HttpPost]
public List<DataModel> GetData(int id, DateTime createDate)
{
    var dataDb = new DataDb(SqlConnectionString);
    var result = dataDb .GetSalesData(id, createDate);
    return result;
}
```

also for calling the the api from c# [HastyApi](https://github.com/lukesampson/HastyAPI) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I tried changing that and I still get same error. "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." I think the problem relies on the way am passing parameter to the stream..am sure am doing something wrong when am calling using HttpWebRequest class

Answer (score 0):

It is sometime quite difficult to understand the underlying issue. Catch the web exception and check the response object from server. It might reveal actual error underneath.

```
catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) response;
                Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
```